# How to delete asset in nested_form through carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, carrierwave, nested-attributes

Good day.
Has somebody working solution for deleting asset in nested form in Carrierwave?

## MODEL

```
has_many :article_images, :dependent => :destroy    
accepts_nested_attributes_for :article_images

mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader    
belongs_to :article, :polymorphic => true
```

## schema.rb

```
create_table "article_images", :force => true do |t|
t.string "image"
t.string "article_id"
end

create_table "articles", :force => true do |t|
t.string "title"
end
```

## CONTROLLER

```
def edit
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
@article.article_images.build
end
```

## VIEW

```
_form.html.erb
<%= f.fields_for :article_images do |article_image| %>
<% if article_image.object.new_record? %>
<%= article_image.file_field :image %>
<% else %>
<%= image_tag(article_image.object.image.url(:thumb)) %>
<%= article_image.check_box :remove_image %> #DON'T WORK
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: [https://github.com/itsNikolay/carrierwave_multiply_files_upload](https://github.com/itsNikolay/carrierwave_multiply_files_upload) All code and repo there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if you add this to your accepts_nested_attributes_for in your model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :article_images, :allow_destroy => true
```

and change this in your view code:

```
<%= article_image.check_box :remove_image %> #DON'T WORK
```

To this:

```
<%= article_image.check_box :_destroy %> #MIGHT WORK?
```

Comment: love for you adam :) for using nested_for _destroy to distroy object ;)

Answer (score 4):

I think it's better if you do this:

```
class ArticleImage < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  attr_accessible :remove_image
  after_save :clean_remove_image

  def changed?
    !!(super || remove_image)
  end

  def clean_remove_image
    self.remove_image = nil
  end
end
```

It worked for me.

Comment: I actually ran into a similar issue with an older version of Mongoid. Just the `changed?` method override worked for me. It looked like the nested object wasn't marked as dirty unless another field in the model was also updated at the same time while trying to remove an image.